# Localize HTML-Page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, localization, multilingual

I have a simple html-page, there I have several text-elements. This I want to localizise, english, german, and so.

Here I found some snippet, but I don't get them to work:
[Handling multilanguage with JQuery only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077989/handling-multilanguage-with-jquery-only)
Why is this not a correct syntax:

## js:

```
label["login"]["fr"]="Connection";
label["login"]["en"]="Login";
...
//some Click-Listener change all language elements
$("*[tag='ist_ml']").each(function() {
    $(this).html(label[$(this).attr("ml_label")]["en"]);
});
//End Click-Listener
```

## html:

```
<label tag='ist_ml' ml_label='login' for='txtLogin'></label>
```

Some help where great, or some other simple ideas.

Comment: why you mean by **I don't get them to work** ? is it regarding the syntactical error or logical error?

Comment: and what syntax error do you get?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: label is not defined, sorry for my bad informations

Comment: Have you declared/instantiated your `label` variable anywhere?

Comment: outside of this method, also is my jQuery selector right $("*[tag='ist_ml']")???

Comment: how to declare my variable right RobH

Comment: hey buddy, i have refined your code and i`m able to make it work. http://jsfiddle.net/VKxX5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the variables before trying to store data:

```
label = {};
label["login"] = {};
label["login"]["fr"]="Connection";
label["login"]["en"]="Login";
```

Or

```
label = {
    login : {
        fr : "Connection",
        en : "Login"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what might be missing, or not be decleard:

```
var label = new Array();
label["login"] = new Array();
label["login"]["en"] = "Bla...";
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has been refined and its working here

**JS CODE:**

```
var lb = {};
lb["login"] = {};

lb["login"]["fr"] = "Connection";
lb["login"]["en"] = "Login";

//some Click-Listener change all language elements
  $("label[class='is']").each(function () {
  $(this).html(lb[$(this).attr("ml_label")]["en"]);
});
//End Click-Listener
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<label class='is' ml_label='login' for='txtLogin'></label>
<label class='is' ml_label='login' for='txtLogin'></label>
```

Here is the J[SFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VKxX5/) to play along with your code

**Live,Dream,Cherish** :)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of minutes late to the party, but here's my working solution for reference:

http://jsfiddle.net/adnrw/jStET/1/

As mentioned above you need to declare the `array()` for `label` before you start adding things to it.